# How to see MongoDB raw queries in real time?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid but the query log it offers is very abstracted, it's far away from ActiveRecord that does a great job showing the raw SQL query. I also checked mongodb log files and it shows queries like:

```
query stock_system.companies query: { $query: { _id: ObjectId('53398f796a756e0e98040000') }, $orderby: { _id: 1 } } ntoreturn:1 idhack:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:40 reslen:2022 0ms
```

But it's still abstracted and it **does not show the queries in nested documents**.

I'm having a hard time debugging queries. I tried to start mongod with profile level 2 and slowms set to -1. But it does not work, any tips?

**#####EDIT: Example of log in nested documents query:**

I'm trying a search in products nested model, like this:

```
current_user.company.products.where({name: /\A#{params[:name]}/}).limit(5)
```

And that query is not logged at all. All it shows is:

```
Processing by AjaxController#products as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"meu", "page"=>"1", "_"=>"1397053974337"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=stock_system collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('532a31376a756e29c9000000')}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.5320ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=stock_system collection=companies selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('532a31376a756e29c9020000')}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.8050ms
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.2ms)
```

Which is the query for the current user and the company, but not the products embedded in the company. I need to see the product raw query to find out what's the problem with that query.

Comment: How does the log not show queries in nested documents? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I just updated the answer to show how Mongoid is loggind in my app.

Comment: This sounds like something you wanna post on the github of mongoid however with you use profiling you should be able to see all queries in one page by looking at the profiling collection

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did that and a contributor from the project told me the problem: "No database query is getting executed - Mongoid is doing this in memory since MongoDB does not support doing queries on embedded documents and returning those documents directly".

Comment: If they are embedded documents then that is quite true. I did not know they were embedded

Comment: Do you know if indexes in embedded documents works since no query in database is being fired, but it's all memory searching?

Comment: They will not, indexes will only be used on actual database calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is that Mongoid fires a database query for the company document but not for the products embedded in it.

If I do a query like:

```
current_user.company.products.where({name: /\A#{params[:name]}/})
```

Company as the root document will be queried from the database, but the products regex query will be executed from a direct memory searching instead of a database query as I was expecting. Hence, there is no log from the products search and all indexes in products will be useless in this case.

If you want to fire a database query to use the index in a embedded document field, use like that:

```
Company.where("products.name" =>  /\A#{params[:name]}/)
```

That is the way to get the specific products in a database query, until MongoDB supports virtual collections for embedded documents.

Answer (score 1):

Make certain that you're setting the profiling level correctly. Should be db.setProfilingLevel(2) to log all activity. Response should look like: { "was" : 0, "slowms" : 100, "ok" : 1 }

Once that's complete you should be able to query the system.profile collection in the database for a log of all activity - db.system.profile.find()

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/

Comment: I tried to set the profiling level in mongod initialization with --profile=2 and logged with mongo and passed db.setProfilingLevel(2). Then I tried what you said, but db.system.profile.find() do not show the raw query either.

Comment: I think the problem is the query is too fast and is not getting logged. That would be a problem since I set slowmn to -1.

Comment: Hi - you don't need to set slowms when using profile level 2. Profile level 2 logs all actions. keep in mind that the system.profile collection is capped - if you have a high transaction rate the query you are looking for can disappear fairly quickly out of the collection. you can pre-create the collection with a larger capped size (directions at bottom of page here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/ Also keep in mind that profiling has an impact on db performance, I would not leave it set at level 2 on a production database for long.

Comment: I see. I just found out the problem, from a contributor of Mongoid project : "No database query is getting executed - Mongoid is doing this in memory since MongoDB does not support doing queries on embedded documents and returning those documents directly" Do you have any details how this memory searching work? Is it possible to debug it?